# How do you define the same tasks differently for different roles in Capistrano?

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I'm using Capistrano to handle my deployment, and I've got two different roles in my setup - :web and :processing. They both have the usual :deploy tasks, but the :restart task needs to be different for the two types of server.

So my first attempt was something like this:

```
task :restart, :roles => :web do
    run "... web related restart stuff ..."
end

task :restart, :roles => :processing do
    run "... processing related restart stuff ..."
end
```

Which doesn't work, because the second :restart (for :processing role) replaces the first :restart (for the :web role), and the :web :restart never happens.

I had a quick look around to see if I could write conditional code depending on which role (or roles) a server might be in when the task is run but there's next to no documentation out there for that kind of thing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You should use namespaces:

```
namespace :web do
  desc "Restart web servers"
  task :restart, :roles => :web do
    # Restart Magic Here
  end
end

namespace :process do
  desc "Restart process servers"
  task :restart, :roles => :process do
    # Restart magic here
  end
end

# Optionally:
task :restart do
  web.restart
  process.restart
end
```

That's what you're looking for I think!

Also, to use these on the command line, you would use

```
$ cap <stage>           # (if using multistage)
$ cap web:restart       # Restarts web servers
$ cap process:restart   # Restarts process servers
$ cap restart           # Restarts both process and web servers
```

(Source: I'm the Capistrano maintainer.)

Answer (score 1):

You should use 'parallel' instead of 'run' in this case:

```
task :restart do
  parallel do |session|
    session.when "in?(:web)", "...substitute run command contents here...."
    session.when "in?(:process)", "...substitute run command contents here...."
  end
end
```

If you are going to use something except 'run' in different tasks you'd better stick to one of the other answers.

More info on 'parallel' command can be found here: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Action-Invokation-Parallel

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call the default `deploy` task, and do some custom restarting, etc. I came up with this solution:

```
# Servers
server "importerhost.com", :app, :web, :db, :importer, :primary => true
server "backuphost.com",   :app, :web, :db, :backup,   :primary => true
set :deploy_to, "/apps/appname"

# Ensure deploy before restart
before 'importer:deploy', 'deploy'
before 'backup:deploy',   'deploy'

# Importer
namespace :importer do
  desc "Restart importer service"
  task :deploy, :roles => :importer do
    sudo "cp #{current_release}/config/importer.conf /etc/init/importer.conf"
    sudo "service importer restart N=1"
    sudo "service importer restart N=2"
  end
end

# Backup
namespace :backup do
  desc "Restart backup service"
  task :deploy, :roles => :backup do
    sudo "cp #{current_release}/config/backup.conf /etc/init/backup.conf"
    sudo "service backup restart"
  end
end
```

And then simply deploy with `cap ROLES=importer importer:deploy`or `cap ROLES=backup backup:deploy`. This gave me the freedom to deploy the same source code to different servers, and execute completely different tasks after the actual deployment.